# Command not found returned in terminal on almost every line

Tags: angularjs, node.js, bash, command-line, terminal

I'm trying to work with AngularJS but I can't even get pass installing it via Terminal.

I enter this onto the command line

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

I get this as a result

```
- bash: npm: command not found
```

I seem to be getting this same error log on almost every command, the rest return nothing

I'm stumped as to why it's not working. 
For reference I'm using OS X 10.9.5

Comment: Please do at least a basic search for the error message before posting here. Search for *bash npm command not found*. A rudimentary search is the extreme minimal effort you can make to find a solution yourself, and you've not even done that yet.

Comment: Wow. I've done a search on youtube, google, and here. Nothing seems to work. No matter what command I type in I always get -bash: npm: command not found.

Comment: Do the search here, on **bash npm not found**, as I suggested two days ago. There are existing posts here, on this very site, which provide solutions to this issue. I gave you the **exact search phrase** to use and told you **exactly where to search**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I needed to adjust the .bash_profile by entering this

```
echo "export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/b‌​in" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Thanks to everyone who gave advice :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you got node installed which comes with npm

https://nodejs.org/en/

Answer (score 0):

You error looks like you don't even have node installed on your computer, first of all, you need to install [node js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) on you computer, once you’ve installed Node.js, you can make sure you’ve got the very most recent version of npm using npm itself: `sudo npm install npm -g`.

Then you can continue your installation with the step below:

To install **@angular/cli** locally run `npm install @angular/cli --save`, while to install it globally run `npm install -g @angular/cli`.

But if it requires a root access, then you have to include the `sudo` which will then be `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`.

Comment: if the `npm` command is not found then she doesn't have npm or node installed.

Comment: I got this -bash: sudo: command not found, I installed NodeJS

Comment: @Ahrianna Did it requested for a root access before installing the `@angular/cli`?

Comment: I was able to fix that issues now I'm presented with another. Installing Angular isn't working due to permissions being denied.